# How to keep placing elements next to eachother without them breaking into a a new line, when they reach window widht?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x:scroll; 
}
.content{
    height: 100px;
}
.box{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I want the boxes next to eachother, even if they overflow on the x axis, outside the container.

I tried setting .content width to a large number, but surely there is an other way.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rvo51gm2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `white-space: nowrap`

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
}

.content{
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, that was exactly what I was looking for!